# return statement just prints one value, print statement prints all the values

Tags: python

I have this method:

```
def filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(file_name):
    output = []
    for token in file_name.split('\n'):
        items = token.split()
        if len(items) > 2 and items[1] in fruit_words:
            output.append((items[1], items[-1]))
            for _, v in output:
                return v

print(filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(verdi50))
```

And it prints just one value: 123,20.

But when I replace return v with: `print(v)`  it prints all the values, when I am calling the method: `print(filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(verdi50))`

```
123,20
2.772,00
46,20
577,50
69,30
3.488,16
137,50
500,00
1.000,00
2.000,00
1.000,00
381,2
```

But this I don't understand. I just return v. and then it prints just one value. If I do a print(v) it prints all the values.

Question: How can I  return all the values in the method, without the print statement?

Comment: `return` causes the function to immediately exit.  So your function stops after just one loop iteration.

Comment: You missed part of the description of your program: Your sample output should include `None` as the last line.

Comment: Another simple fix could be to replace return with yield, then: for i in filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(file_name): print(i) but admittedly that's not the easiest to understand/manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return all the values in `output` as a list, change this:

```
            for _, v in output:
                return v
```

to this:

```
    return [v for _, v in output]
```

Note that it needs to be outside of the `for` loop (i.e. de-indented to the same level as `output = []`) so that it won't happen until you've finished building the entire `output` list.

You could also write this as a list comprehension rather than `append`ing to a list, e.g.:

```
def filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(file_contents):
    return [
        items[-1] for items in (
            token.split() for token in file_contents.split('\n')
        ) if len(items) > 2 and items[1] in fruit_words
    ]
```

Comment: This still causes the function to immediately exit.  All subsequent iterations of the outer `for token in ...` loop are skipped.

Comment: This works. Oke, I didn't knew this. Thank you. if I do this: print(filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(verdi50)) it prints all the values

Comment: Need to de-indent to make sure it happens outside the loop -- updated to that effect.

Comment: @Samwise is the second solution better for performance?

Comment: Very slightly (because you aren't building an extra list), but really it's more about simplicity/brevity and avoiding deeply nested blocks.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke the `return`statement, your function is stopped and returns a value.

You can print the elements outside the function like this, returning the array with all the tuples.

```
def filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(file_name):
    output = []
    for token in file_name.split('\n'):
        items = token.split()
        if len(items) > 2 and items[1] in fruit_words:
            output.append((items[1], items[-1]))
    return [v for _, v in output]

print(x for x in filter_verdi_total_fruit_cost(verdi50))
```

Comment: This explains the problem, but does not answer the question.  The question was "How can I return all the values in the method", and this does not address that at all.

Comment: Just edited! Please have a look again. Thanks!